# LinearLayout doesn't work properly

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-imageview

[image]

How can I put the `TextView` exactly below the `ImageView`?
I write the code below, but it put the `TextView` with margin below the image,
I also try different `scaleType` for `ImageView`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_row_logo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/nature_bg" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hello" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: add `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` in ImageView xml.

Comment: @mohammad can you post or `nature_bg` image ? it may have blank space

Comment: user114... image doesn't have blank space , I'm sure.

Comment: @Mohammad please provide screenshot with problem

Comment: android:adjustViewBounds="true" worked. thank you @dhaval-patel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add [android:adjustViewBounds="true"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:adjustViewBounds) attribute for ImageView. Set this to true will adjust its bounds to preserve the aspect ratio of its drawable.

```
<ImageView
      android:id="@+id/list_row_logo"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_margin="0dp"
      android:padding="0dp"
      android:adjustViewBounds="true"
      android:src="@drawable/beekeeper_logo" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a relativeLayout instead, and place the textview below the image like that :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_row_logo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/nature_bg" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hello"
            android:layout_below="@id/list_row_logo"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```